# How do I upload an attachment to a document in CouchDB using ibrowse?

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I have used curl to upload an image file `Penguins.jpg`. For example:
    `C:\curl>curl -vX PUT -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" http://localhost:5984/DBNAME/DOCID/Penguins?rev=LATEST_REVISION --data-binary @Penguins.jpg`

and it worked...

So, how can I achieve the same using ibrowse?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ===============================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally, a file upload is an `HTTP POST` . Now lets first write piece of Erlang code which does `HTTP/1.1 POST with Ibrowse` .

```
%% Assumes Ibrowse application is in Code path
ensure_ibrowse()->
    case whereis(ibrowse) of
        undefined -> ibrowse:start();
        _ -> ok
    end.

post(Link,Data,Headers)-> 
    ensure_ibrowse(),
    try ibrowse:send_req(Link,Headers,post,Data) of 
        { _, _, _,Result} -> 
            io:format("\n\tFile Uploaded. Return: ~p~n",[Result]);
        EE -> {error,EE}
    catch
        XX:XX2 -> {error,XX,XX2}
    end.
```

From there, lets do our Couch DB thing.

```
-define(Link,"http://localhost:5984/DBNAME/DOCID/Penguins?rev=LATEST_REVISION").

%% File_path must be a valid file !
upload_file(Full_file_path)->
    case file:read_file(Full_file_path) of
        {ok,Binary} ->
            post(?Link,Binary,[{"Content-Type","image/jpeg"}]);
        Error -> Error
    end.
```

There you go ! All you need to do is to customize your Macro `Link` to fit your couch DB settings and you're good to go !

Comment: If the file is big, it might need to be sent in chunks in which case the headers would include something similar to this: `{ "Content-Type" ,  "multipart/form-data" }`