# Image upload to facebook with erlang binaries

Tags: facebook-graph-api, erlang

I am working with the Facebook Ads API, and I have an issue with uploading images to Facebook.

Here is the [Facebook Syntax Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adimage/).

Could any one suggest to me a way to upload an image to Facebook in Erlang Http client (am using Ibrowse)?

In Erlang we have to upload image using binary data, but Facebook doesn't allow us to upload binary data.

Facebook Syntax :

```
curl -F 'test.zip=@test.zip' -F 'access_token=___' "https://graph.facebook.com/act_368811234/adimages"
```

In Erlang we can't upload an image like `test.zip=@test.zip`. How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [this question] that could give you some clues.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167534/how-do-i-upload-an-attachment-to-a-document-in-couchdb-using-ibrowse)

Comment: Hmmm.. I achieved that by using linux curl command from erlang.